# Windows Server 2019 2 node failover cluster offline after some reboot

Tags: windows-server-2019, failovercluster

I have 2 windows server 2019 on VirtualBox. I have configured the failover cluster and it's working. I'm testing the failover and failback.
These are the steps I have done after completing the configuration (Testing with IIS website).

1. Start Node 1 (Only Node1 on, Node 1 Website Available on virtual IP)
2. Start Node 2 (Both Node on, Node 1 Website Available on virtual IP)
3. Shutdown Node 1 (Only Node2 on, Node 2 Website Available on virtual IP)
4. Shutdown Node 2, Now both nodes are off.

After 10 minutes.

5. Start Node 1 (No website available on virtual IP, but available on node 1 physical)

Now failover cluster manager shows "Cluster status: down".

Does anyone know why node 1 does not start the cluster as in step 1?
Note that these actions are done within 1 hour.
Is this may be the issue of node Quarantine?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not related to the quarantine. When the node is quarantined you will see it in the Failover Cluster manager. In your scenario, you are shutting down node 1 first and then node 2. After booting node 1 cluster is offline due to dynamic quorum mechanism. Check for more information:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askcore/failover-cluster-node-startup-order-in-windows-server-2012-r2
Failover Cluster with 2 nodes only should have an external Witness. It can be a file share witness or a witness disk. The following guide should help:
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/resource-library/starwind-virtual-san-for-hyper-v-2-node-hyperconverged-scenario-with-windows-server-2016/